# What is the minimum length of the Thue-Morse sequence needed to traverse before finding a substring of length $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Thue-Morse sequence is an infinite sequence. Suppose I have to search for a substring of length $n$ in this sequence. What should be the minimum length of the Thue-Morse sequence needed to search my string of length $n$?